# How to create a url shortcut by python

Tags: python, shortcut, win32com

I want to create a shortcut by python pywin32, but the code doesnot work.

the following is my code , I donnot know why i cannot create a shortcut by it !
Please help me check it, thanks for your help~

```
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import win32com.client

bmurl = unicode(r"http://www.pystack.org/","utf8")
bmpath = unicode(r"C:\Users\moose\Desktop\bm\blog.url","utf8")

ws = win32com.client.Dispatch("wscript.shell")
scut = ws.CreateShortcut(bmpath)
scut.TargetPath=bmurl  
scut.Save
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the error is that `Save` is a method. You need to call it if you want to perform the corresponding action. Try to replace the last line by

```
scut.Save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call `scut.Save`. It is a method and should have been called here.
Just add the parenthesis :

```
scut.Save()
```